# Difference in minutes from two time fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, time

I set up my MySQL database with the field 'time'

It is not HH:MM in the traditional sense, it is the time an event occurred, so an event with the value of 5:45 occurred with 5 minutes 45 seconds left in a game. 12:25 occurred with 12 minutes and 25 seconds left, etc.

I would like to be able to find out the total time elapsed, so if I have an event that occurred at 12:25 and the next event occurred at 5:45 I want to be able to get the difference, which would be equal to 6:40. Then, I would like to express this as a decimal, in this case 6.67.

Is this possible?

Comment: what data type have you used to store these values?

Comment: @Brian I used 'time' data type since there was no date attached.

Comment: l made the same mistake too. you dont work with time type columns when later you are on operations like this. you always store in minutes (decimals) for later process, is more easy to filter.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just use

```
TIMEDIFF(fromtime, totime):

SELECT TIMEDIFF("12:25", "5:45");
```

If you need a decimal, use `TIME_TO_SEC()/3600` (it assumes you passed it seconds, but the format you're storing the times in is vague and SQL probably will interpret them as HH:MM - you can fix this with `CONCAT("00:",MinuteSecondField)` maybe?) - then you can use `TIME_TO_SEC()/60`, which is more correct)

Comment: Oh also since you imply the database is your own design - maybe consider using a TIMESTAMP field, or an INTEGER field (and just store seconds in it - divide by 60 to get your minute.second decimal value)

Answer (score 75):

For me this worked:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, T0.created, T0.modified)
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I had no idea TIMESTAMPDIFF existed!

Answer (score 22):

I needed similar. Two useful functions: [TIME_TO_SEC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) and [SUBTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime).

e.g. if your time fields were normal HH:MM times, then

```
SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(end_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(start_time))/60 AS `minutes`
```

In your case, as I understand it, the times are backwards, ie. `12:00<6:00` so your end_time and start_time would need swapping.

If you wanted the output in HH:MM:SS you could do

```
SELECT SUBTIME(end_time, start_time)
```

Answer (score 4):

I used UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event1)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event2), which gives you seconds between events. Divide it by 60.0 and you will get a decimal as per your requirement. This solution assumes, your columns are date-compatible values. It will work really fast if they are TIMESTAMPs.

UPDATE: This solution only works with timestamp data types, not time datatypes as in original question.

Comment: Questionner says they setup the field as a time field. UNIX_TIMESTAMP requires datetime/timestamp field; will not work

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants the result as an **Integer**:

```sql
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('12:25', '12:45')) DIV 60;
```

Or if only **Positive Integer** is required:

```sql
SELECT ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('12:25', '12:45')) DIV 60);
```