# SQL/PHP - Can I create starttime and endtime in seperate column by adding minutes in the third?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three columns in a table in Mysql - Starttime, endtime and minutes

Can I add (with PHP) "minutes" to the table 'minutes' so it automatically
create the starttime and endtime (datetime) by using starttime as current_time ?

So if it´s now 02:32 and I add in the minute-field 14 then
the 'starttime' would have 2014-07-02 02:32 and 'endtime' have 2014-07-02 02:46

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can. You can even do this in SQL.

Comment: you dont need the third column, you can calculate the diff in minutes in mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070111/difference-in-minutes-from-two-time-fields-in-mysql

Comment: It´s veru complicated - the user has to post minutes - but there have to be record of the endtime and starttime

Answer (score 0):

This could be a PHP answer, but my recommendation would be to do it with MySQL

```
$minutes = 14;
$starttime = new DateTime();
date_add($starttime, date_interval_create_from_date_string($minutes . ' minutes'));
$endtime = date_format($starttime, 'Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just doing it in your insert query at the time of adding the minutes to the database. Let MySQL do the calculations for you.

```
INSERT INTO foo (minutes, starttime, endtime) VALUES ( 14, NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 MINUTE) );
```