# calculate time difference in minutes between timestamp from the same column mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I have a table with these two columns (plus some others that are not relevant):

transaction_pk and value_timestamp

I would like to get the time difference (in minutes) for each transaction_pk. Each transaction_pk has many rows and i'm not looking for difference between 1st and last timestamp

Example table

```
transaction_pk    |   status_timestamp
1                 |   2020-02-11 19:14:45
1                 |   2020-02-11 19:18:45
1                 |   2020-02-11 19:15:45
2                 |   2020-02-11 19:18:45
2                 |   2020-02-11 19:14:45
2                 |   2020-02-11 19:19:45
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
transaction_pk    |   status_timestamp     | time_diff
1                 |   2020-02-11 19:14:45  | 0
1                 |   2020-02-11 19:18:45  | 04:00
1                 |   2020-02-11 19:20:45  | 02:00
2                 |   2020-02-11 19:18:45  | 0
2                 |   2020-02-11 19:14:45  | 04:00
2                 |   2020-02-11 19:19:45  | 05:00
```

I have tried the following question:

[Calculate the difference in minutes between timestamp mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860825/calculate-the-difference-in-minutes-between-timestamp-mysql)

but I get the following error message when I try and execute the code

#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'report_db.x.connector_pk' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

*Edit - this now works after running the following:

SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

It does however take a long time to run. Is there a way to make it quicker and also to update my table rather than just run a query.

Comment: The solution for "warning, your SQL isn't compatible with ONLY FULL GROUP BY" isn't to turn off the warning..

Comment: @CaiusJard could you elaborate on that. What would the solution be?

Comment: Assuming that a query like `SELECT a,b FROM t GROUP BY a` raises the complaint from MySQL, the solution is to decide what to do with b; either group it or aggregate it. Turning off the warning and leaving it open, just makes MySQL pick some value of `b` at random, as though you'd said `SELECT a, ANY_SINGLE(b) FROM ...`

Comment: thank you @CaiusJard. Is this why the query is taking so long? The query I used has select x.* and Group By transaction_pk, value_timestamp; Does that mean it has all the columns in the table and then only grouping by two of them. I appreciate you taking the time to respond to my questions by the way.

Comment: It's not really an impediment to performance to group by some and select all, but it doesn't really make sense. If you consider that the grouping operation is just taking all the rows and chucking them into a unique set of buckets labelled with whatever you're grouping by, then the values swimming round int he buckets have lost all sense of the row they came from, so what you get when you ask for a value, if you don't exactly specify what you want, is anyone's guess. If your table had columns `a` and `b` and values of `1,100`,`1,200` and `1,300`, and you do `SELECT a,b FROM t GROUP BY a`..

Comment: ..then you really need to specify which `b` you want.. i.e. `MIN(b)` will make sure you get 100, `MAX(b)` makes sure you get 300, `AVG(b)` gives 200.. But just omitting it/asking for `b` might give you 200 this time, and 300 next time then 100 the time after that when you run the query.. How can anyone write a sensible, logical computer program on the back of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a fan of putting subqueries in the SELECT but it's a way of solving this problem for ancient versions of MySQL:

```
SELECT 
  transaction_pk,
  status_timestamp,
  (SELECT MAX(tsub.status_timestamp) FROM t tsub WHERE tsub.transaction_pk = tmain.transaction_pk and tsub.status_timestamp < tmain.status_timestamp) as last_timestamp
FROM
  t tmain
```

You can use it like you would any other value in e.g. a call to timestampdiff:

```
SELECT 
  transaction_pk,
  status_timestamp,
  COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    SECOND,
    (SELECT MAX(tsub.status_timestamp) FROM test tsub WHERE tsub.transaction_pk = tmain.transaction_pk and tsub.status_timestamp < tmain.status_timestamp),
    status_timestamp
  )/60.0, 0) as diff
FROM
  t tmain
```

The COALESCE converts the NULL that results from the first value per PK not having any "timestamp less than the current", into a 0.. otherwise, the idea of diffing on the seconds then dividing by 60 gives us a decimal representation of the number of fractional minutes since the previous time. If you need greater precision, use a smaller time interval and a greater divisor respectively

Comment: that was a really quick way of answering the query. It took 0.2 sec as opposed to over 30 seconds for the previous one I was using. Could you explain how I add the result to a column of the table i'm querying please?

Comment: do you know why this query takes so long to run when part of a CREATE VIEW xx AS query?

Comment: It might be best to post that up as a new question, with the SQL you're running and the execution plan the DB is preparing for it. I'm not personally sure why a view would take a long time to create, because it's conceptually not creating anything other than storing an SQL statement that will be run when the view is selected from.. The storing of an SQL should be quick, the slow part should be when querying the view in future rather than creating it

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard I have been playing around with this and it turns out I hadn't indexed the table (it was a copy from another db). Its running quicker now 17 sec rather than 400, but could still be quicker. I'm trying to work out how to add a unique column to the table now...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.transaction_pk, 
       t1.status_timestamp,
       COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t2.status_timestamp, t1.status_timestamp), 0) time_diff
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.transaction_pk = t2.transaction_pk
                 AND t1.status_timestamp > t2.status_timestamp
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM test t3
                   WHERE t1.transaction_pk = t3.transaction_pk
                     AND t1.status_timestamp > t3.status_timestamp
                     AND t3.status_timestamp > t2.status_timestamp )
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=196ea4febb7071ff46eea79ba79f58d5)

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work Akina. It came back with negative times and the first row for each transaction_pk has a negative value rather than a zero. The code I quote above works, but I can't add it to my current table

Comment: @RDC_Green Provided fiddle shows correct output - check.

Comment: I checked and its still showing negative numbers. The solution provided by Caius Jard works better and is much quicker. Thank you for your help