# How to calculator time in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem when I try get the total number of minutes in 2 rows. For example:

[image]

I don't know in mysql how to calculate this time with a query.

I want get minutes of 1 rows include `time start` and `time end` to use it.

Comment: the time start and time end, is a parameter or is in a table?

Comment: `time end`, `time start` is in a table. And all is in 1 rows on a table.

Comment: duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070111/difference-in-minutes-from-two-time-fields-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query...

```
SELECT ((HOUR('time end') * 60) + MINUTE('time end')) - ((HOUR('time start') * 60) + MINUTE('time start'))
```