# change status after 1 hour and after 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have installed a cron job to run automatically. It checks for the jobs in the database and after one hour it should change from private to public status and after 24 hours it should change from public to expired. The cron job is running smoothly but the following code is not bringing the desired outcome. The database data doesn't change and when I run it myself, nothing is being shown as a message.

How can I twist it so that it achieves that?

My code:

```
      // Check and do something: private to public
      $now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
      $timeBefore=strtotime($now-3600);
      $check=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ibirakas WHERE status='private' AND added<'$timeBefore'") or die(mysql_error());
      while($exe_check=mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)){
        $id=$exe_check['kiraka_id'];
        $query=mysql_query("UPDATE ibirakas SET status='public' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
        if($query==true){
          echo "CRON_1_DONE";
        } else {
          echo "CRON_1_FAIL";
        }
      }
      //check and do something: public to expired
      $now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
      $timeBefore=strtotime($now-86400);
      $check=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ibirakas WHERE status='public' AND added<'$timeBefore'") or die(mysql_error());
      while($exe_check=mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)){
        $id=$exe_check['kiraka_id'];
        $query=mysql_query("UPDATE ibirakas SET status='expired' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
        if($query==true){
          echo "CRON_2_DONE";
        } else {
          echo "CRON_2_FAIL";
        }
      }
```

I have included connect.php file and also i have opened the php open and close tags(which are not included here)
Your help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `== TRUE`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as true so that literal comparison is redundant.

Comment: I was also going to mention PDO off the bat, though given all the variables are internally generated by the program, you don't have any open injection bugs, unless PHP misbehaves or your kiraka_id is already open to injection. You should be using PDO and escaping regardless. But, have you done the usual debugging? Where does it fail? Do you get back the data you expect, but it doesn't update?

Comment: Thanks for that reference, I needed it @tadman

Comment: I receive no output and the data doesn’t change. So I do not really know where the problem lays

Comment: One more thing: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code. In your code here you confused the two.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make it much easier without so much PHP and work more with MySQL functions. There are a lot functions like `TIMEDIFF` so you could check if the difference from `NOW()` to the saved date is bigger then 90 minutes. Here is a good question how to get minutes from your diff.

[Difference in minutes from two time fields in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070111/difference-in-minutes-from-two-time-fields-in-mysql)

Then you don't need so select and update all your rows. You can directly update all that rows that match your conditions.

Comment: Yes, I see I don’t have to reselect all rows. Can you please provide a syntax that shows how that can be done? Time difference? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find a relevant answer to this question. Since I wanted to use MySQL in the first place, this simple solution did it.

```
      <?php
      include("connect.php");
      date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Kigali");
      // Change from private to public
      $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ibirakas WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(),`added`))>3600 AND status='private'");
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $change=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ibirakas SET status='public'");
      }
      // Change from public to expired
      $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ibirakas WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(),`added`))>86400 AND status='public'");
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $change=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ibirakas SET status='expired'");
      }
      ?>
```

Thanks