# Calculate time difference between 2 (non consecutive) rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm newbie in SQL and I'm trying to compare two hours and see the difference between rows in columns "diff plan" and "diff done".

How can I achieve this?

Thank you! :)

```
date                id          planned     done       diff plan    diff done
21/10/2019 00:00    3252250 A   05:00:00    04:59:04        NULL      NULL
21/10/2019 00:00    3251855 A   05:00:00    05:00:18    00:00:00    00:01:14
21/10/2019 00:00    3251868 A   05:07:00    05:07:30    00:07:00    00:07:12
21/10/2019 00:00    3252291 A   05:10:00    05:10:47    00:03:00    00:03:17
```

Comment: What version of mySQL.  window/analytic functions Lead() or Lag() could potentially do this if you have those available.  Otherwise, it gets more complicated.

Comment: I think he wants the difference between them. For example 3rd row would be 12 seconds assuming it's h m s

Comment: 5.6.40- version

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for MySQL < 8.0, where window functions are not available. This assumes that column `done` can be used to *order* the records (you can change every occurence of `done` to some other column if that's more relevant for your use case):

```
select
    t.*,
    timediff(t.planned, tlag.planned) diff_plan,
    timediff(t.done,    tlag.done) diff_done
from mytable t
left join mytable tlag
    on tlag.done < t.done
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where t1.done < t.done and t1.done > tlag.done
    )
order by t.done
```

This works by self-joining each record with its preceeding record (for this, we use a `not exists` condition with a correlated subquery, that ensures that there is no record in between the current record and the one being joined). Then, we use function `timediff()` to compute the time difference for columns `planned` and `done`.

**[Demo on MySQL 5.6 DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDCkcZ2a3fFBYRLqFZo4bM/0)**:

Sample data:

```
| date       | id      | planned  | done     |
| ---------- | ------- | -------- | -------- |
| 2019-10-21 | 3252250 | 05:00:00 | 04:59:04 |
| 2019-10-21 | 3251855 | 05:00:00 | 05:00:18 |
| 2019-10-21 | 3251868 | 05:07:00 | 05:07:30 |
| 2019-10-21 | 3252291 | 05:10:00 | 05:10:47 |
```

Results:

```
| date       | id      | planned  | done     | diff_plan | diff_done |
| ---------- | ------- | -------- | -------- | --------- | --------- |
| 2019-10-21 | 3252250 | 05:00:00 | 04:59:04 |           |           |
| 2019-10-21 | 3251855 | 05:00:00 | 05:00:18 | 00:00:00  | 00:01:14  |
| 2019-10-21 | 3251868 | 05:07:00 | 05:07:30 | 00:07:00  | 00:07:12  |
| 2019-10-21 | 3252291 | 05:10:00 | 05:10:47 | 00:03:00  | 00:03:17  |
```

Comment: Thank you, GMB! I think it will work for me. I'm trying to execute, but my table have 2GB, is running but I still don't get results. You think I'll have performance issues?

Comment: @tainaamoraes: with this query, you want an index on `done` for performance (or whatever column you use for ordering). Please be sure to have that index in place.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070111/difference-in-minutes-from-two-time-fields-in-mysql). It might help you.

`TIMEDIFF` function will find difference between two times.

Comment: Thank you!
I try this, but I don't know how to compare between previous and current row. Is this possible?

Comment: Ok, means you want to compare time between rows, not between columns diff plan and diff done. I will update my answer.